# Power Automate Flow Error with Access Denied (Creating sharing link)

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I've created a flow to manage data input into various sharepoint lists as well file uploads. The trigger is an MS Form and this has been working well for a couple of months. Today for some reason it was run however it failed stating access denied when creating a sharing link.

Since the last time it was run successfully, there has been zero changes to the flow, the sharepoint Lists or Folders. The only update has been the addition of a view and another flow for a different process.

I've checked through the permissions and the flow is run from my account and I have full access to the sharepoint site. I've tried to manually create a share link but there is no issues.

Does anyone have any guidance on what to check to correct this issue?

[image]

Unsure whether the below raw output will be helpful?

```
{
"statusCode": 403,
"headers": {
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "X-SharePointHealthScore": "1",
    "X-SP-SERVERSTATE": "ReadOnly=0",
    "ODATA-VERSION": "4.0",
    "SPClientServiceRequestDuration": "114",
    "SPRequestGuid": "9042f985-3113-42da-94c5-19853be88dc3",
    "request-id": "9042f985-3113-42da-94c5-19853be88dc3",
    "MS-CV": "hflCkBMx2kKUxRmFO+iNww.0",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
    "X-FRAME-OPTIONS": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "Content-Security-Policy": "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com *.officeapps.live.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com;",
    "MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices": "16.0.0.21010",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-MS-InvokeApp": "1; RequireReadOnly",
    "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Date": "Thu, 25 Feb 2021 13:54:59 GMT",
    "P3P": "CP=\"ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI\"",
    "X-AspNet-Version": "4.0.30319",
    "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
    "Content-Length": "84",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Expires": "-1"
},
"body": {
    "error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "Access denied"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried recreating your SharePoint connector connection? I have seen some issues when security setting such as Multi Factor Authentication are applied to an account used in Power Automate, Flows.

Comment: Thank you Simon, I had recreated the flow on a new Sharepoint page as it was an access error.